# How to continue downloading components after cancel it when using android studio for the first time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

When I running android studio for the first time it asked me to install some android components but I canceled it in the half way.
And when I running it again, it told me that "[No Android SDK found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UpPE.png)" but when I click "Next", It told me that [Android SDK has already been installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpQbv.png) so it can do nothing.
I've cleared the folder I install the android sdk initially and reinstall android studio, but it doesnenter image description here't work.
God, do I have to reinstall my system to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to go to SDK Manager (in Android Studio on the right of the toolbar) ? Then choose a location for your SDK and choose a image to download.

[image: SDK Manager ScreenShot]

Comment: when I click "edit", the second image I posted will pop up.

Comment: Don't click on edit unless you want to change your SDK path. Choose the SQK platform you want to download in the SDK Platforms (eg. Android API 27) check the box and click on apply at the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > System Settings > Android SDK > on the right side click on Edit Link > It will take you to the same download page that you get at the start of android studio.

Peace.